# How to dynamically deduce types from an interface with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

The TypeScript [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) describe how to make use of function overloads.

In the following use case is an example of a staticly defined overload function.

```
interface MyObject {
    a: boolean
    b: number
}

const myObject: MyObject = {
    a: true,
    b: 1
}

function getValueOfMyObject (key: 'a'): boolean
function getValueOfMyObject (key: 'b'): number
function getValueOfMyObject (key: keyof MyObject): boolean | number {
    return myObject[key]
}
```

So,

`getValueOfMyObject('a')` will have a `boolean` as return type, and

`getValueOfMyObject('b')` will have a `number` as return type.

For my use case I don't want to type out more overloads for every new property in the MyObject interface. I am looking for a solution to have a dynamic return type. A way that TypeScript automatically deducts the return type based on the MyObject interface. Something like:

```
function getValueOfMyObject (key: keyof MyObject): typeof MyObject[key] {
    return myObject[key]
}
```

This however doesn't seem to be the right syntax. Is there any way to achieve this with TypeScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a type parameter to capture the actual literal type that the function is called with. With this type parameter we can then index into te `MyObject` type.

```
interface MyObject {
    a: boolean
    b: number
}

const myObject: MyObject = {
    a: true,
    b: 1
}
function getValueOfMyObject<K extends keyof MyObject>(key: K): MyObject[K] {
    return myObject[key]
}
getValueOfMyObject('a') // K is 'a', returns boolean
getValueOfMyObject('b') // K is 'b', returns number
```